# Get output of system ping without printing to the console

Tags: python

I want to call `ping` from Python and get the output.  I tried the following:

```
response = os.system("ping "+ "- c")
```

However, this prints to the console, which I don't want.

```
PING 10.10.0.100 (10.10.0.100) 56(86) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.0.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.713 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.15 ms
```

Is there a way to not print to the console and just get the result?

Comment: Get *what* result? The ping stdout output or the status code of the process?

Comment: I  just want to know if the machine is up or not.

Comment: @user1704282 What if the machine is up, but not responding to ping?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the output of a command, use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).  It raises an error if the command fails, so surround it in a `try` block.

```
import subprocess

try:
    response = subprocess.check_output(
        ['ping', '-c', '3', '10.10.0.100'],
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  # get all output
        universal_newlines=True  # return string not bytes
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    response = None
```

---

To use `ping` to know whether an address is responding, use its return value, which is 0 for success.  [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) will raise and error if the return value is not 0.  To suppress output, redirect `stdout` and `stderr`.  With Python 3 you can use `subprocess.DEVNULL` rather than opening the null file in a block.

```
import os
import subprocess

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(
            ['ping', '-c', '3', '10.10.0.100'],
            stdout=DEVNULL,  # suppress output
            stderr=DEVNULL
        )
        is_up = True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        is_up = False
```

---

<sub>In general, use `subprocess` calls, which, as the docs describe, are intended to replace `os.system`.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

If you only need to check if the ping was successful, look at the status code; `ping` returns `2` for a failed ping, `0` for a success.

I'd use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (and *not* `subprocess.check_call()` as that raises an exception when `ping` reports the host is down, complicating handling). Redirect `stdout` to a pipe so you can read it from Python:

```
ipaddress = '198.252.206.140'  # guess who
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ping', '-c', '3', ipaddress],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode == 0:
    print('{} is UP'.format(ipaddress))
    print('ping output:')
    print(stdout.decode('ASCII'))
```

You can switch to [`subprocess.DEVNULL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL)<sup>*</sup> if you want to ignore the output; use `proc.wait()` to wait for `ping` to exit; you can add `-q` to have `ping` do less work, as it'll produce less output with that switch:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ping', '-q', '-c', '3', ipaddress],
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
proc.wait()
if proc.returncode == 0:
    print('{} is UP'.format(ipaddress))
```

In both cases, `proc.returncode` can tell you more about why the ping failed, depending on your `ping` implementation. See `man ping` for details. On OS X the manpage states:

```
EXIT STATUS
     The ping utility exits with one of the following values:

     0       At least one response was heard from the specified host.

     2       The transmission was successful but no responses were received.

     any other value
             An error occurred.  These values are defined in <sysexits.h>.
```

and `man sysexits` lists further error codes.

The latter form (ignoring the output) can be simplified by using [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), which combines the `proc.wait()` with a `proc.returncode` return:

```
status = subprocess.call(
    ['ping', '-q', '-c', '3', ipaddress],
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
if status == 0:
    print('{} is UP'.format(ipaddress))
```

---

<sup>*</sup> `subprocess.DEVNULL` is new in Python 3.3; use `open(os.devnull, 'wb')` in it's place in older Python versions, making use of the [`os.devnull` value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.devnull), e.g.:

```
status = subprocess.call(
    ['ping', '-q', '-c', '3', ipaddress],
    stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'))
```

Comment: How can we add a "time limit" for this test?. For example, if the ping request "hangs" => then there are several cases you can wait forever. can we limit the test for (for example) 10 seconds and then check output?

Comment: @Kosem: The `subprocess` module supports timeouts. In the above example, you could use `proc.wait(timeout=<seconds>)`, or pass the same argument to the `subprocess.call()` examples.

Comment: @sorh without version information and errors I can’t help you make things work. I've retested all the examples in my answer on Python 3.8 and they all still work for me.

Comment: eventually I manage to run it, the '-c' switch wasn't working for some reason, however this wasn't good for me either since the cmd window pops up briefly every time it runs..

Comment: @sorh: `-c` is the 'count' option. If you are using Windows, check the documentation for the ping command and see what command-line options are supported. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping) suggests you need to use `/n` (or `-n`) instead of `-c`, and there doesn't appear an equivalent switch for `-q`. However, that seems to apply to Windows Server only.

Comment: 2021, still works fine for me on newest Python: `def PingDevice(device):` `return(device) if subprocess.call(["ping","-n","2","-w","500",str(device)], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL) == 0 else None`

Comment: for those on Linux systems:  `result = os.system('ping -c 1 "+hostToPing)` is faster, cleaner, and less overhead.