# Supress OS command prompt popup in python

Tags: python, ping

```
import subprocess, platform

def ping(host):
    args = "ping -n 1 " + host
    return subprocess.call(args) == 0
```

print(ping("www.google.com"))

I am using this code in order to ping a website to test whether it is up or down, which works perfectly, however it results in a command prompt window briefly appearing which is not ideal for what I am working on, so my question is;
How can I supress this window from appearing on pings requests (windows based solution needed)

Comment: `subprocess.call(args,stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)` for python 3

Comment: The command window still appears briefly when using this?

Comment: ah yes, pass `,startupinfo` argument: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/409002-launching-a-subprocess-without-a-console-window/

Answer (score -1):

To use ping to know whether an address is responding, use its return value, which is 0 for success.  subprocess.check_call will raise and error if the return value is not 0. To suppress output, redirect stdout and stderr. With Python 3 you can use subprocess.DEVNULL rather than opening the null file in a block.

```
import os
import subprocess

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(
            ['ping', '-c', '3', '10.10.0.100'],
            stdout=DEVNULL,  # suppress output
            stderr=DEVNULL
        )
        is_up = True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        is_up = False
```

Ref:[Get output of system ping without printing to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769023/get-output-of-system-ping-without-printing-to-the-console)

Comment: don't answer, just flag as duplicate, since it's one and you copied Davidsim code in his answer

Comment: ok, got it will take care